# Regex string with spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have very big difficulties to find a regex for string with spaces (it can use every letter and number). It length should be from 5 to 25 characters.

Help!

Comment: `str.indexOf(' ') !== -1` <-- true if space exists.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem, all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against. Also, please include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following regex will match any string that is between 5 and 25 characters (inclusive), containing only digits, letters (uppercase and lowercase), and the space character specifically (ascii 0x20):

`[a-zA-Z0-9\x20]{5,25}`

Replace `\x20` with `\s` to include other "white-spaces", like tabs and line-breaks.

**EDIT**:

@MikeM is correct; Unless this is anchored it will greedily match *each* instance of a 5-25 char string within the target (that is, eg a 30 character string *containing* a valid 25 character string of allowed letters would still return a match on that 25 character substring) which is obviously not what the OP wants.

So, regex above should be updated to ensure it only returns a single match, and only when the entire target is between 5 and 25 characters long, as follows:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9\x20]{5,25}$`

Comment: a literal white space is also valid inside JS regexes as far as I know.

Comment: Needs anchoring with `^` and `$` otherwise the maximum length stipulation is pointless.

Comment: @MikeM Thanks mate, you're right of course.  My answer updated to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want

```
^(?=(\s*[a-zA-Z\d]){5,25}$).*$
```

This would match 5 to 25 number of digits or alphabets with any number of spaces between them